# Â appearing before some characters in xml feed

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I have a xml feed with some html in one of my nodes.
So basically making it like this in php

```
<user_id>'.$review[user_id].'</user_id>
<content>'.htmlspecialchars(bbcode($review[content])).'</content>
<content_bbcode>'.htmlspecialchars($review[content]).'</content_bbcode>
<added_date>'.$review[added_date].'</added_date>
```

The xml is ISO-8859-1 encoding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

There aren't any more headers.

On the other end I'm just using simplexml_load_string to get the file and break it all up into it's component parts (nodes).

My problem is that for some characters '£' for example and others Â appears before the character and in other occasions they don't display at all. My website is also in ISO-8859-1. Does anyone know any reason for this or the work around.

I heard some stuff about iconv but that doesn't seem to want to work.
Other ideas are to make a str_replace script, but that sounds a little complicated and I can't get all the characters.

Thanks for any help.
Richard

Comment: just a guess - source data might be in UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I think I just went in and removed them.
Richard

Answer (score 2):

How do you use `iconv`? Try this before outputting:

```
$review['content'] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $review['content']);
```

P.S. Not related to "Â" problem, but you're probably missing quotes around array keys - it should be `$review['content']`, not `$review[content]`. Same for other places where `$review` array is used.

Comment: I gave it a go just before the and no go - is this before I output it ie print to html? or on the xml?
Cheers
Richard

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending the output in UTF-8, yet specifying the charset as Latin-1. Do you have the correct charset on your database *connection*?

The MySQL query `SET NAMES latin1` will convert the all the following data coming from a DB connection to be in ISO-8859-1 (Latin1).

Comment: The charset for the tables are already in latin1. Isn't this enough?

Comment: I've just ran it through the w3c validator and it says that it is UTF-8 but I've said ISO-8859-1 in the header - I really don't get all this charset stuff. I'm a nube when it comes to that! any light you can shine would be great.

Comment: @Richard Housham: It should be - unless the *connection* charset is specified (could be), then MySQL will convert the data to the connection charset before sending them to you. Also, check what HTTP headers you're sending - you might be sending something like `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`. The validator is IIRC sniffing the content - it really looks that the data is UTF-8, regardless of what the metadata (in the header) says.

Comment: Cheers for getting back to me, I've added the line 
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset:ISO-8859-1');
To the top of the xml which says that it is returning ISO-8859-1 but still these weird A's appear. 

It's difficult to help when you are on the other side of the world ;)

Like I say I'm a nube on this stuff so any further ideas would be great.